# Test delay to server from a different locaton

Tags: networking, web, hybrid-mobile-app

I have set up some CDN servers for my web app. Now I can test the speed from L.A by curl the files from the server. However, now I want to test if it's as fast in other locations, like New York, what can I do for that purpose?

Comment: How about AWS EC2 instance at other geography?

Comment: That's a good idea.